# Pylance en VSCode es muy lento (1133 ms para ejecutarse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode

en estos momentos estoy intentando hacer un proyecto para la universidad donde el detalle que me esta sucediendo, es que para que se me despliegue las opciones o que el mismo IDE identifique que algo es una variable tarda demasiado con Python, ya que con cualquier otro lenguaje se tarda milesimas de segundo, mientras que con Python tarda demasiado y he estado investigando donde dicen que uno de los problemas es el servidor del lenguaje "Jedi", donde si se cambia a Pylance funciona, pero el detalle es que yo ya lo tenía en Pylance y checando las extenciones y cuanto se tardan en ejecutar me encontre que dura demasiado a comparación a otras extensiones. No sé si realmente exista una solución para esto, gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]